# Help identifying this rear-wheel part (photo)

Tags: rear-wheel, axle

I took off my rear wheel, and this fell out on the floor:

[image]

Is this a "**rear wheel axle**"?

It looks like it should indeed be in one piece instead of two. I would like to order a replacement for this part(s) without having to replace the entire rear wheel.

Comment: What you have there is a broken axle.

Comment: I'll add that this is not a terribly unusual failure, and may not be terribly expensive to fix.  The cups, spacers, and locknuts can be removed from the broken axle and a new axle (purchased at a modest cost or "borrowed" from a spare bike) substituted.  And of course you should get new ball bearings.  What gets messy is if the mating "cones" in the hub have been damaged -- then it's usually cheaper to replace the entire wheel.

Comment: I found it was cheaper to buy an axle +cones +locknuts +wheel nuts in a blister pack, than it was to buy an axle and a single cone separately.   Shop around, or rescue one from a dumpster bike's rear wheel.  Your city might have a bike co-op who can assist too.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It's hard to say while the cones aren't clean, but the driveside cone looks very worn.

Comment: @Alexander - Yeah, what I meant to say was "cups".  The cones are visible in the picture but grease-covered, and would need a close inspection anyway.  The cups are in the hub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a broken rear axle.
If you nave no proper tools (freewheel/cassette remover, cone wrench 15mm, wrench 17mm, new QR axle, 2 rings of new bearings), get it to an LBS to replace it.
It's also recommended to check the wheel bearings cups for defects, it maybe a good time to replace the wheel - all depends on the shape of other parts, and the cost to bring it to proper state.

Comment: If all you're doing is replacing the axle, there's no need to remove the cassette.

Comment: If the axle has got to this state I'd put bets on the cassette being worn to a point where it looks like a shoal of sharks.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak you're assuming it is a cassette.  A freewheel generally must come off to get to the drive-side cup.

Comment: Although it can be done with cassette in place, its usually a lot easier to remove the cassette to replace the axle.

Comment: Actually this axle is for a freewheel, not cassette. They all brakes in the same place. It can be done putting the bearing balls through the freewheel gap, greased (so they will stick to place). The cones looks pretty worn thou, so i'll prefer to remove the freewheel and check the cups.

Comment: I wanted to replace the cassette when, yes, I've realised that I have a freewheel instead. I will be looking to buy a freewheel.

Comment: @eoinoc Usually it's recommended to replace the chain with the freewheel, to reduce the wear of the new freewheel, but with cheap parts as you probably have, this maybe not important.